# Boot stuck at logo screen after upgrading to 14.10

Tags: boot, 14.10

After upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10 my computer cannot boot anymore, it is stuck at the logo screen (with animated dots).

By displaying the boot process, I see that it is stuck at "Stopping log initial device creation". When I press Ctrl+Alt+F2, only a flickering dash appears, and I can't even log in.

[image]

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I could finally log in after waiting for 3 hours :|

Comment: i am facing the same problem. Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @ShankhoneerChakrovarty: Unfortunately I didn't, and finally had to reinstall the OS.